# Loading DLL file in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a C++ program that loads a dll(a.dll). It should run in
combination with wine in Linux. In the dll a function foo will be called
which takes two strings and an integer. foo returns an integer. The dll
is located in the same directory as the exe. Unfortunately the dll file
is not found and I don't know why. I have also tried "./a.dll" under
Linux. Can anyone give me some advice on this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
#include <tchar.h>

typedef int(*func_ptr)(std::string, std::string, int);

int main()
{
    func_ptr function1 = NULL;
   
    HMODULE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"a.dll");
    if (hGetProcIDDLL != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Found!";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File not found!";
        return 0;
    }
    function1 = (func_ptr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "foo");
    if (function1 != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << function1("input-file.txt","output-file.txt",0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Function not found";
    }
    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
    std::cin.get();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You should call `GetLastError` after the call to `LoadLibrary` and then look up the meaning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: There are 3 possible reasons for not being able to load a dll. (1) wrong path, note: if you are using an IDE the current working directory is usually not the same directory as the one the program is in; (2) missing some of the dll's dependencies; (3) wrong architecture (64-bit trying to load 32-bit or the other way about).  Eliminate some the above and as @Andy said post the result from `GetLastError`.

Comment: Never use relative paths, always use absolute paths. Since the DLL is in the same folder as the EXE, you can query the EXE's path at runtime using `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` and then replace the EXE filename with the DLL filename. Also, note that it is not safe to pass `std::string` over the DLL boundary like this code is doing. You have to use `char*` strings instead.

Comment: Besides that, caller and callee need to agree on a [calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions). `func_ptr` doesn't specify a calling convention, delegating the outcome of calling a function through that function pointer to luck.